# Second Record Occurs When the Form is Resubmitted by Pressing the Back Key from the Browser

Tags: python, django

When the user fills in the form and saves it, they are redirected to the next page. However, when the user presses the back button from the browser, the completed form is brought to the user from the browser cache. The user thinks that the form has been edited and when he/she makes the necessary edits and resubmits the form, a second record is created in the database.

```
class UserFormView(FormView):
    def get(self, request, userformmodel_id = None):
        instance = get_object_or_404(models.UserFormModel, pk=userformmodel_id) if userformmodel_id else None
        form = forms.UserFormForm(instance=instance) if instance else forms.UserFormForm()

        context = {
            'form' : form,
        }
        return render(request, 'formuser.html', context)

    def post(self, request, userformmodel_id=None):
        instance = get_object_or_404(models.UserFormModel, pk=userformmodel_id) if userformmodel _id else None
        form = forms.UserFormForm(request.POST, instance=instance) if instance else forms.UserFormForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(user_id=request.user.id)
            return redirect('other-page')
 
        context = {
            'form' : form,
     I
        }
        return render(request, 'userform.html', context)
```

I couldn't find any solution. The only solution is not to redirect the user to another page after submitting the form.